# Ratio of some complex numbers' differences and equality of norm of them

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help with the following question .

> Suppose that the complex numbers $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ satisfy the equality
> $$
> \frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3}.
> $$
> Prove that $|z_2-z_1| = |z_3-z_1| = |z_2-z_3|$. Hint: Argue geometrically interpreting the meaning of each statement.

I thought I should saw these three vectors form a triangle because of the hint. Then I called the norms as $a$, $b$, $c$ and applied the triangle inequality. But it is not true. I got $\frac ab=\frac bc=k$. We should find $k$ can only be $1$. But from triangle inequality it does not have to be $1$. It can be a number close to $1$ like $0.8$ or $1.2$.

So, am I doing it wrong? Is $0$ there any other way?
(I also tried polar coordinates and naming the vectors like $\frac tu=-\frac u{t-u}$. Maybe these give an idea to you. But I'm more focused on trigonometric inequalities because of the hint.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks you to prove $\triangle z_1z_2z_3$ is equilateral given that $$\tag{*}\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1}=\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2}=A.$$ First, you should verify for yourself that the angle at $z_1$ is $\arg(A)$ which is equal to the angle at $z_3$. Hence  $\triangle z_1z_2z_3$ is at least isosceles.

I  rewrote the condition in $(*)$ slightly since now we have $$\begin{split} z_2-z_1=A(z_3-z_1)&=A^2(z_3-z_2)\\ \implies\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_2-z_3}&=-A^2,\end{split}$$ but since $\triangle z_1z_2z_3$ is isosceles, $$\lvert -A^2\rvert=1\implies \lvert A\rvert=1$$ and we conclude all side lengths are equal. $\qquad\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_2-z_1=a_3 e^{i\theta_3}, z_3-z_1=a_2 e^{i\theta_2}$ and $z_2-z_3=a_1 e^{i\theta_1}$, with $a_1,a_2>0,a_3\geq0$; Taking the arguments of each member of the given equality, we get $arg(\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_3-z_1})=arg(\frac{z_1-z_3}{z_2-z_3})$, otherwise written the triangle is isosceles at $z_2$; so, $a_1=a_3$ (1). Then, taking the modules, $\frac{a_3}{a_2}=\frac{a_2}{a_1}$. So $a_2^2-a_1^2=(a_2-a_1)(a_2+a_1)=0$. So, $a_2=a_1$(2). From (1) and (2), we conclude.